# ms-access sort order a column with commas based on query?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is there a way to sort a column that has data separated by commas in order of any of the data between the commas:

[image: current]

So i need to be able to sort by column3 for abc or efg or even hij, and then sort them by that search/query.

So if i search/query efg and sort it it would look something like this in access.

[image: result]

Comment: are you trying to sort or filter? if you are sorting then your result does not match!

Comment: nope filtering still does the same thing as what i was doing by query. I will go back to messing around in VB moduling, Thanks anyway Hiten004

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want the rows where `column3` contains *",efg"*, and you want to sort the result set based on that substring.  You can get that with this query in an Access session.

```sql
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM YourTable
WHERE column3 Like '*,efg*'
ORDER BY Mid(column3, InStr(column3, ',efg'));
```

If you will be running the query from outside an Access session, and using ADO/OleDb, change the wild card characters.

```sql
WHERE column3 Like '%,efg%'
```

Comment: Yeah i did that in the query wizard thing, but it doesn't sort by efg, it sorts by the first characters in the string so what ever is in the first comma.

I need to sort by the data between the commas. Is it possible? is there something i can learn or read that will point me in the right direction?

Comment: HansUp, thanks man this Totally does what i want it to. Thanks. Didn't know you could do that with Order by.

Answer (score 0):

Select * from table1 where instr(col3,',') > 0

Please try this sql and use your table and col name. Good luck.